# Windows и Linux в Qt Creator

Tags: linux, windows, qt, qtcreator, виджет

Работаю на **Windows 10** в **Qt Creator**.

Можно ли в **Qt Creator** под Windows сделать приложение `Qt Widgets` под **Linux**?

Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Линусков слишком много и все они разные.

При написании программы следует придерживаться ряда правил, в частности, не выходить за пределы Qt и C++, не использовать платформенно-зависимые API.

А потом нужно взять ваши исходники, взять нужный вам дистр линукса и собраться на нем.

Comment: Спасибо, а собирать я так понимаю обязательно также через Qt?

Comment: нет, собирать через  Qt не обязательно. скорее всего `qmake . && make` все сделает